# Type error when trying to print row number

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I have this game of battleship that prints out a grid (row of 5 'o's printed 5x) and generates a random point for the user to guess.

These are the lines: 16-20

```
""" Allows the function to print row by row """
    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            for x in enumerate(row):
                print('%s " ".join(row)' % (x))
```

I'm getting these errors. But it was only after I changed line 20 to print the number alongside the printed grid (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRBUZ.jpg) picture there

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Jarrall\pythonPrac\battleship.py", line 23, in <module>
    print_board(board)   File "C:\Users\Jarrall\pythonPrac\battleship.py", line 20, in print_board
    print('%s " ".join(row)' % (x)) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**How would I get that piece of code to print a number (enumerating the length of the row list?) alongside the grid?**

Comment: Just fyi, your docstring should be *inside* the function, after the signature and indented to the same level as the outermost `for`.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `enumerate` wrong. I am not completely sure but it looks to me like you want it to print something like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0
```

This can be done by `enumerate(board)` since `enumerate` returns an index and the iterator:

```
def print_board(board):
    for index,row in enumerate(board):
        print('{} {}'.format(index, ' '.join(row))
```

So that you can get:

```
>>> board = [['0' for _ in range(5)] for __ in range(5)]
>>> print_board(board)
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0
```

EDIT - to add why your current `print` statement needed some fixin':

Your `print` statement doesnt do what you expected it to do. Let's walk through it:

```
print('%s " ".join(row)' % (x))
     #'                ' will create a string literal. This is obvious.
     # %s                a string formatting token meaning to replace with a string
     #                   % (x) the replacement for any of the string formatting
     #    " ".join(row)  this is your vital flaw. Although this is valid code, the print
     #                   statement will print this as literally `" ".join(row)
     #                   rather than actually running the code.
```

That is why you needed to change it to:

```
print('{} {}'.format(index, ' '.join(row))
#shout-out to jpmc26 for changing this
```

This replaces all instances of `{}` with the arguments given in `format`. You can learn more about the mini-language that has to do with string formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: I made an edit to the `print` call since it wasn't Python 2.7 compatible (although it worked in Python 3.x). You might also want to mention something about the differences with the `print` command, since the OP seemed confused about how to use string formatting.

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks for the edit, am re-editing right now to add explanation. Accidentally clicked on the edit load box while middle of my edit and lost all of what I already had *why must I do this to myself*

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess from your stack trace, I'd say you need to cast the x variable to a string, like this:

```
print('%s " ".join(row)' % (str(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's enumerate method returns a tuple of 0-indexed integers along with the list value. So rather than simply being a value in row, your x variable is actually (integer, row). If you just want to print a list of integers, change your inner loop to the following:

```
for x,y in enumerate(row):
    print('%s " ".join(row)' % (x))
```

This should solve your problem. If you want a more specific answer, please specify exactly what you are trying to do along with what the row variable is.